# Grouping arrays based on duration string

Tags: javascript

I need to group elements in different containers based on overlapping periods. Let's say we have the following array:

```js
const periods = ['1-4', '1-7', '1-4', '1-8', '1-8', '5-8', '9-12', '9-12'];
```

I need it to turn into:

```js
[['1-4', '5-8', '9-12'], ['1-7', '9-12'], ['1-4'], ['1-8'], ['1-8']]
```

Basically, elements get pushed into a "row". If the element's period overlaps with another inside the current row, it would create another one.

In this example `'1-4', '5-8' and '9-12'` are grouped because their periods do not overlap.

I'm doing this with DOM elements, I used arrays in an attempt to simplify things. Any ideas?

Comment: What if there was one more variable in the mix?

Input: `[{duration: '1-4', el: 'something'}, {duration: '5-8', el: 'something'}, {duration: '1-4', el: 'something'}...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayby this code can help you to solve your case.

```
const periods = ["1-4", "1-7", "1-4", "1-8", "1-8", "5-8", "9-12", "9-12"];

const groupPeriods = (periods) => {
  const groups = {};
  const listOfPeriodsGlobal = [...periods];

  for (let i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
    const joinPeriods = [];
    const listOfPeriods = [...listOfPeriodsGlobal];

    for (let j = 0; j < listOfPeriods.length; j++) {
      if (isInRange(listOfPeriods[j], joinPeriods)) {
        joinPeriods.push(listOfPeriods[j]);
        listOfPeriodsGlobal.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }

    groups[i] = joinPeriods;
  }
  return groups;
};

const isInRange = (period, joinPeriods) => {
  let respose = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < joinPeriods.length; i++) {
    const range = joinPeriods[i];
    const rangesplited = range.split("-");
    const periodsplited = period.split("-");

    if (
      (parseInt(periodsplited[0]) >= parseInt(rangesplited[0]) &&
        parseInt(periodsplited[0]) <= parseInt(rangesplited[1])) ||
      (parseInt(periodsplited[1]) >= parseInt(rangesplited[0]) &&
        parseInt(periodsplited[1]) <= parseInt(rangesplited[1]))
    ) {
      respose = false;
    } else {
      response = true;
    }
  }

  return respose;
};

console.log(groupPeriods(periods));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could find the group with checking the last value against the start value.

```js
const
    periods = ['1-4', '1-7', '1-4', '1-8', '1-8', '5-8', '9-12', '9-12'],
    groups = periods.reduce((r, p) => {
        const
            start = +p.split('-', 1),
            t = r.find(a => +a.at(-1).split('-')[1] < start);
            
        if (t) t.push(p);
        else r.push([p]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```